# Kafka connect with Cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

i am using the Kafka for multiple purpose , but i want to use the connect API of Kafka but i wont be able to understand the differences of why to use Kafka connect instead of writing our own consumer group and write the message in any database without going write complex thing and without adding other packages like confluent does in Kafka-connect.

Answer (score 2):

Connect as a framework takes care of fail-over and you can also run it in distributed mode to scale out you data import/export "job". Thus, Connect is really a "fire and forget" experience. Furthermore, for Connect, you don't need to write any code -- you just configure the connector.

If you built this manually, you basically solve issues that got solved by Connect already (ie, reinvent the wheel). Don't underestimate the complexity of this task -- it sound straight forward on the surface, but its more complex as it seems to be.

Comment: there is one major problem for using connector class is exception handling . if json data does not matched with the required format the connector gives an exception like "ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted"

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect offers a useful abstraction for both users and developers who want to move data in and out of Apache Kafka.

Users may pick a Connector out of a constantly growing [collection of existing Connectors](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) and, by just submitting appropriate configuration, integrate their data with Kafka quickly and efficiently. Developers can implement a Connector for their special use case, without having to worry about low level management of a cluster of producers and consumers and how to make such a cluster scale (as [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4953079/matthias-j-sax) mentioned already).

As it often happens with software, if a particular software abstraction doesn't fit your needs, you may have to go down one or more abstraction levels and write your code by using lower level constructs. In our case these are the Kafka producer and consumer, which are still a pretty robust and easy to use abstraction for moving data in and out of Kafka.

Now to get to the specific point you are referring to, which is what is often called handling of bad or incompatible data in Kafka Connect, this is something that is mostly a responsibility of the Connector developer at the moment. However, we intend to provide ways for the framework to facilitate such handling of bad data and make it more a matter of configuration rather than Connector implementation. That's in the roadmap for the near future.